# Derivative of Grassmann exponential

Tags: exponential-function

Can anyone explain how to correctly carry out a derivative of a Grassmann exponential. Consider $e^{\theta}$ where $\theta$ is Grassmannian. Since, $\theta^2 = 0$ we have $$e^{\theta} = 1+\theta$$
And, hence,
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}e^{\theta} = 1$$ which is obviously incorrect. Can someone please suggest the correct way to implement differentiation of a Grassmann exponential?

Comment: Why would that be incorrect?  Since $e^{\theta}=1$ at $\theta=0$, and the derivative of $e^{\theta}$ at $\theta=0$ (and everywhere else) is $1$, and all higher derivatives are $0$... you've shown that $e^{\theta}$ is linear (of course), and in fact is equal to $1+\theta$.  Everything you wrote is consistent.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Are you saying that Grassmann derivatives automatically implement derivation at $\theta = 0$?

Comment: The grassmannian tag refers to something entirely different.

Comment: Can you perhaps enlighten us as to what "grassmannian" mean in your context? All I know about grassmanian is the Grassmannian manifold. Perhaps $\theta$ refers to an element of the tangent space of a Grassmannian manifold?

Comment: @SangchulLee Sorry, I meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number.

Comment: I'm saying you're right that $(d/d\theta) e^{\theta}=1$.  Indeed, the derivative of any function of a single Grassmann variable is a constant.  And I'm asking why you think it's "obviously incorrect".